# How to force all strings to floats?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a small dataframe, consisting of just two columns, which should have all floats in it.  So, I have two fields name 'Price' and 'Score'.  When I look at the data, it all looks like floats to me, but apparently something is a string.  Is there some way to kick out these things that are strings, but look like floats?  Or, is there a way to force everything to be float?  The error occurs on the last line show here, and then nothing else works.

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\my_path\\analytics.csv')
print('done!')
modDF = df[['Price', 'Score']].copy()
modDF = modDF[:100]
for i_dataset, dataset in enumerate(datasets):
    X, y = dataset
    # normalize dataset for easier parameter selection
    X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
```

Here is the Stack Trace:

```
datasets = [modDF]
for i_dataset, dataset in enumerate(datasets):
    X, y = dataset
    # normalize dataset for easier parameter selection
    X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-18-013c2a6bef49>", line 5, in <module>
    X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)

  File "C:\Users\rs\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 553, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)

  File "C:\Users\rs\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 639, in fit
    return self.partial_fit(X, y)

  File "C:\Users\rs\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 663, in partial_fit
    force_all_finite='allow-nan')

  File "C:\Users\rs\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 496, in check_array
    array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)

  File "C:\Users\rs\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Price'
```

Comment: What is the error message that is returned?

Comment: X.astype(float) ?

Comment: @Raphael I would think that would error out if any of the data is a string, even if it looks like a float.

Comment: Right @EdekiOkoh. I forgot he wants to remove the strings.

Comment: can you show `modDF['price'].unique()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change data type of columns in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-data-type-of-columns-in-pandas)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using [pd.to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) like so:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce', downcast='float')
```

Which would try to convert your data to float, and the data that is not float will be returned as Nan.

Then

```
df.dropna(how='any', axis=0, inplace=True)
```

which just drops any rows with at least 1 Nan value in it.

Comment: I tried that and the code ran fine.  I just tested this: modDF.dtypes.  I have two fields; both are float32.  Now, I'm trying to fit the independent variables and I'm getting the same error that I initially had.  The data set looks fine to me.  Apparently Python doesn't like something about my setup.  I just don't know what.

Comment: Can you post the exact trackback of the error message? And did you run modDF.dtypes before or after converting

Comment: Based on the traceback Price is not a float. What is the dtype after pd.to_numeric?

Comment: I got rid of those two features and pushed several others into the modified dataframe.  Now everything works fine.